# How to format dates in Laravel Excel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-excel

I want to ask, how can we validate dates from Excel file. I have encountered some weird test cases below.

Firstly, I have inputted **5/13/2021** in my excel file, but when I dump in, it doesn't display same, instead it displays **44329**.

But fortunately I could able to display to **5/13/2021** using the following codes:

```
$temp = Carbon::instance(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value));
$datetime = Carbon::parse($temp);
```

---

So, my big problem here is I can't use `before` or `after` validations. Like below codes it always fail even though, I fill it in correctly.

```
return Validator::make($rows->toArray(), [
            '*.0' => 'required|after:now|before:0.1' //publish_at
            '*.1' => 'required|before:0.0' // expired_at
        ])->validate();
```

As you can see in the picture below, the value of `publish_at` is **44329**, and `expired_at` is **44330**. I don't know why it fails. I tried also `gt` or `lt` validation it still fails.

[image]

Someone knows how to do it. would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the validation, it looks like you know which columns are going to be dates. With this knowledge, I believe you may be able to implement the [WithCustomValueBinder](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/concerns.html) concern to achieve dates formatted to your liking.

This is a quick and dirty example to show how a predefined array of columns could be formatted as date strings. Update column letters and date format as desired. Obviously, you will need to add in your preferred import method and validation.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomValueBinder;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\DefaultValueBinder;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataType;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;

class SampleImport extends DefaultValueBinder implements WithCustomValueBinder
{
    // set the preferred date format
    private $date_format = 'Y-m-d';

    // set the columns to be formatted as dates
    private $date_columns = ['A','B'];

    // bind date formats to column defined above
    public function bindValue(Cell $cell, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($cell->getColumn(), $this->date_columns)) {
            $cell->setValueExplicit(Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value)->format($this->date_format), DataType::TYPE_STRING);

            return true;
        }

        // else return default behavior
        return parent::bindValue($cell, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. i fix it through this documentation, pls. accept my edits.  https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/custom-formatting-values.html#custom-formatting-values

Comment: Glad you got it working. Someone had already rejected the edits, but I made updates based on the docs linked. The original code had worked in my basic testing, but this update makes sense.

Comment: np. by the way also read. this another way of formatting dates in this doc.link  https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/import/dates.html#format-dates

Comment: Is that for a different version of Laravel Excel? I don't see those methods in the [PHPSpreadSheet docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I tried applying them to the reader using events but it did not work. I'd be interested to know if you got that working on 3.x.

Comment: haven't tried it yet. just sharin. but i'm now okay with your answer.